# How to fill ACF meta key with custom taxonomy term under publish_post hook?

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata, hook

Hy everybody.

With the Advanced Custom Fields plugin, I've created a meta key (price_ord) for a custom post type (marca).
Whereas the values for this meta key have to be the same as the terms of a taxonomy (prezzo) attached to marca post, 
I like to fill automatically this meta key when I pubblish a new post, avoiding a double insertion.

My idea was to retrieve the term of the taxonomy and use it to update the meta key, when I click the Upload button on new custom post type page.
I've tried this solution, but doesn't work, because the meta key remains empty.

Do I mistake the use of that hook?
Could someone give me some advice, please?

```
function update_post_price() {
    global $post;
    $id = $post->ID;
    $price_terms = get_the_terms( $id, 'prezzo' );
    if ($price_terms) {
      foreach($price_terms as $price_term) {
        if ($price_term->parent != 0) { // avoid parent categories
            $updated_meta = $price_term;
        }
      }
    }
    if ($updated_meta) {
        update_field( 'prezzo_ord', $updated_meta, $post_id);
    }
}
add_action( 'publish_marca', 'update_post_price', 10, 2 );
```